# In jQuery textarea result value showing like [object HTMLTextAreaElement]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In my program, I have written a script and form like this:

**jQuery :**

```
 var message1 = $('#message').val();
```

**Form :**

```
<label>Message</label>
<textarea rows="4" name="message" id="message" class="required"></textarea>
```

I am getting the var message1 result is `[object HTMLTextAreaElement]` 
Whats wrong in my code?

Comment: I tried your code and its working fine please provide more detail

Comment: He probably had $('#message') before as that was him returning the object. But yes, the code is correct.

Comment: Your code is fine.Check in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/v48sy2db/

Comment: Are you using any plugin for textarea like tinymce..?

Comment: Please provide full code. The provided code looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the textarea element itself. To get its value, add `.value`

Answer (score 0):

You might try to use

```
var message1 = $('#message').html();
```

I'm pretty sure the .val() function gets the value attribute and the textarea doesn't use this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It may that you haven't used any jQuery library to use jQuery syntax? although this syntax

```
 var message1 = $('#message').val();
```

is correct, I have checked this.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery when the content is enclosed within the tags like div, span or textarea then you have to find the value of content using .html() or .text()

Difference between these two is that .html() returns the full html content of that element whereas .text() returns the exact text value of the content excluding the html tags.